# Can we get the protractor test status in onComplete

Tags: protractor

I am running my script in 3 browsers as distributed test execution. I need to get the status of test after executing the script in all browsers and i need to update the DB according to this test status. That is, if all the browsers successfully completed the execution, then the status should be passed and if any of the browser execution get failed, then the status should be failed. So i need to execute a sql query after the execution in all the browsers with the test status. Can we use onComplete function for this? how can i do this? Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom reporter that using jasmine listeners.
Each specific function returns results that can indicate a issue with the test or suite or jasmine itself.

More info here: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

```
interface CustomReporter {
        jasmineStarted?(suiteInfo: SuiteInfo): void;
        suiteStarted?(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
        specStarted?(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
        specDone?(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
        suiteDone?(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
        jasmineDone?(runDetails: RunDetails): void;
    }
```